# While loop stops no error or warning message in Xilinx SDK on Zynq processor

Tags: c, sdk, embedded, fpga, xilinx-ise

I am using a sensor and reading values from it. I have added `uart_lite` in the xilinx EDK and mapped it's pins to the boards GPIO. The PS (Zynq PS) clock is 50Mhz/100Mhz/200Mhz.
I am receiving data from the RX of UART at 115200 baud rate with 2 stop bits and even parity.

I am using the UART using the registers provided in the document. Four registers are there: `ctrl_reg`, `stat_reg`, `RX_reg`, `TX_reg`. Using these I can configure my uart to receive data and transmit data.  Here is the [documentation for `uartlite`](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/xps_uartlite.pdf).

Now I am receiving data in and trying to print the data on Teraterm.

Here is the code to set up the uart in correct mode and its registers.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "platform.h"
    #include "xparameters.h"
    #include "xil_io.h"
    #include "sleep.h"


    #define UART_BASE       XPAR_AXI_UARTLITE_0_BASEADDR
    #define RX_FIFO_REG     UART_BASE + 0x00
    #define TX_FIFO_REG     UART_BASE + 0x04
    #define STAT_REG        UART_BASE + 0x08
    #define CTRL_REG        UART_BASE + 0x0C

    // Control Register
    #define ENA_INTR        27
    #define RST_RXFIFO      30
    #define RST_TXFIFO      31
    // Control Register

    // xsp module
    unsigned int *pAddr;
    #define RS_DXEN         0
    #define RS_UART_OUI     1
    #define RS_HF_OUT       2
    #define RS_RXEN_BAR     3
    #define RS_TE_485       4
    unsigned int Setting;
    // xsp module

    unsigned int *pData1, *pData2, *pData3, *pData4;
    unsigned int RxStat = 0;
    unsigned int RxData = 0;


    int main()
    {
        init_platform();
        pAddr = XPAR_UART_IP_0_BASEADDR;

// RS485 RX Mode
Setting = ( 0<<RS_TE_485 | 0<<RS_RXEN_BAR | 1<<RS_HF_OUT | 1<<RS_UART_OUI | 0<<RS_DXEN );
 // RS485 TX Mode
//Setting = ( 0<<RS_TE_485 | 1<<RS_RXEN_BAR | 1<<RS_HF_OUT | 1<<RS_UART_OUI | 1<<RS_DXEN );
*pAddr = Setting;
 // Control Register
pData1  = CTRL_REG;
*pData1  = (1<<ENA_INTR)|(1<RST_RXFIFO)|(1<RST_TXFIFO);
pData2  = RX_FIFO_REG;//FIFO REG;
pData3  = STAT_REG;//STAT_REG;
pData4  = TX_FIFO_REG; // TX_FIFO_REG

    while (1) {
        xil_printf("success");
            xil_printf("0x%X\r\n",*pData2);
         }

        return 0;
    }
```

So My while loop should continuously run and print values but it stops only after printing 18 bytes??
but My output is like this: 
[image]

Here is my debug try: 
[image]

Comment: Time to hook up the built-in debugger, and start stepping through the code on the MicroBlaze.

Comment: Hi @JonathonReinhart can you download the image I added of debugger screen ? and see my debug trial ?

Comment: Why is `init_platform` being called multiple times?

Comment: Well when I click step over command 5 times the arrow remains at the init_paltform(), then at the 6th click it goes to the second line and again at some line where // RS485 RX Mode,  (settings = something something ) ; is there it completes in 4-5 clicks. So some commands get multiple times. I think in just one step_over the init_platform() didn't get completed i.e the the platform couldn't be completely initialized maybe?